# wxPython installation on ubuntu 16.04 taking very long time

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, wxpython

I am trying to install wxPython on ubuntu 16.04 for python3 using pip3, but after downloading the requirements it stuck in installing it. I have installed the required development packages and their dependencies as mentioned [here](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/README.rst#prerequisites).

[image: screenshot of the installation process where it get stuck]

Comment: Ended up using pre-built builds from `conda-forge` as suggested on the `wxpython` project webpage. https://wxpython.org/pages/downloads/

Answer (score 7):

It takes a long time to build, be patient and it will probably make it through if the needed library dependencies are installed.  You can use the `--verbose` flag on pip to see what it is doing along the way.

Alternatively, there are already wheel files available for Ubuntu 16.04, see https://wxpython.org/pages/downloads/

Comment: Also, there is more info here if you need to build it yourself: https://wxpython.org/blog/2017-08-17-builds-for-linux-with-pip/index.html

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by RobinDunn use Linux Wheels:

```
pip install -U \
    -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-16.04 \
    wxPython
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt install python3-wxgtk4.0`

package in Ubuntu 20.04 which will get you version 4.0.7. Works also 22.04